# Why do i have running,turn,and flashers but no headlights?

Tags: headlight, jeep, fuse, relay, grand-cherokee

My 1994 grand cherokee has running lights ,turn signals, and flashers,but no headlights,high or low beam. ive replaced the relays in the distribution block checked all fuses.  What am i missing or over looking?

Comment: Do you have autolamps? Did you check for voltage out of the switch? Is there voltage to the bulb? Are the bulbs grounded?

Comment: ive repslaced the switch and now finding what wire supplys the voltage to the headlight socket itself, is there a shop repair manual thats free to download?

Comment: How's the ground? As for a shop manual you can generally pay some money to tech info sites for 1 day access and download stuff for your car. Check out https://www.techauthority.com/

Comment: no autolamps, just running, signal and flasher. however the highbeam icon lights up when the switch is pulled back. there was voltage comingout of the  switch harness the last time i checked it wich was before i changed the switch.

Comment: Check the grounds AT the lights.  Voltage out of the switch does not mean *current* through the bulbs.